# Отказоустойчивость системы

Tags: архитектура, highload

Есть сервер, на который с различных сервисов и веб-сайтов поступает информация (отправленные формы - лиды). С этого сервера информация уходит в другие различные системы + сохраняется в БД.
Возник вопрос, как обеспечить отказойсточивость?
У меня такие варианты:

1. Сделать дубль текущего сервера, в другом ДЦ, и выделить отдельную
   машину под load balancer. Но тут вопрос - а что будет, если упадёт
   машина где расположен load balancer?
2. Сделать дубль текущего сервера, и во всех скриптах, которые
   отсылают запросы на сервер(со стороны клиента) внести функцию отправки данных на
   дублирующий сервер в случае, если после отправки данных на первый
   сервер не пришел положительный ответ. И настроить синхронизацию БД
   двух серверов.

Как вы считаете, какой вариант лучше? Либо предложите свой.
Заранее благодарен за советы.

Comment: Второй выглядит костыльным и богатым на баги.

Comment: Согласен, но в первом варианте главный вопрос - как быть если упадёт сам load balancer? Получается он становится слабым звеном

Comment: Соответственно - дублировать балансер, делать high availability на уровне DNS.